# Some linked list C macro questions

Tags: c, linked-list

I am looking at two linked list implementations ([queue.h](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sys/sys/queue.h) [[source](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sys/sys/queue.h?rev=1.37;content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)] and [utlist.h](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/utlist.html) [[source](https://github.com/troydhanson/uthash/blob/master/src/utlist.h)]), and I have a few questions regarding their respective implementations:

1. What is `_Q_INVALIDATE` all about in queue.h? I suppose it is part of some debugging, but I don't really understand the macro `define` logic.
2. Both implementations offer `FOREACH` and `FOREACH_SAFE`. The former is straight forward, but what is the logic behind the second? Also, if the former is unsafe in anyway, why has it been implemented in the first place?
3. Why has `queue.h` implemented its struct as having different types for `next` and `prev` (`struct *le_next` and `struct **le_prev`)?
4. In both implementations, why are there extra parenthesis inserted here and there? Eg. around `head` in `#define LIST_FIRST(head) ((head)->lh_first)`

Comment: For #4 see: [Use parentheses within macros around parameter names](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE01-C.+Use+parentheses+within+macros+around+parameter+names)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Question 1:

`_Q_INVALIDATE` is a macro that sets a pointer that should no longer be used to a value of `-1`. The intent is that if it is used subsequently, debugging will be made easier because using the pointer will cause an immediate crash.  In non-debug mode the macro does nothing, so the pointer is left with its current value - if there's a bug that results in the pointer being used, the problem may be a much more subtle defect.

For Question 2:

The 'safe' versions of these macros take an additional pointer argument that the macro uses internally to point to the next item in the list while the current one is being processed.  This allows the code inside the loop to remove the current item from the list. Since the next item has already been remembered in the temp pointer, the macro has no problem picking it up for the next iteration.  The non-safe version of the macro doesn't use a temp pointer, so you can't remove the current item from the list while iterating it.

For Question 3:

This makes it easier to add a new element before the current one or to remove the current element from the list without concern about whether the current element is at the head of the list (and therefore only 'pointed to' by the list pointer) or if the current element is elsewhere in the list (and therefore pointed to by another element's `le_next` pointer). If `le_prev` were a `struct type*` then dealing with the first element in the list would need special case code. Since `le_prev` is a `struct type**` it can refer to a simple `struct type*` (like the list head pointer) just as easily as a `struct type*` that's embedded at some arbitrary offset inside `type` (like the `le_next` links in each element).

Question 4 was answered in a comment above.

Comment: Superb. I didn't really get the -1 part about Question 1. Pretty clever way of signaling improper use of pointers. Thanks much!